# If a sequence converges to 0 it's reciprocal need not be infinite

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm trying to show that $(a_{n}) \to 0$ then $(\frac{1}{(a_{n})}) \to \infty$ is false.

As a counter example I have $(a_{n}) = \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$. This converges to 0, but for the reciprocal we have that $\frac{1}{a_{2n}} \to \infty$ and $\frac{1}{a_{2n-1}} \to -\infty$

I'm struggling to formally show that $\frac{1}{a_{2n}} \to \infty$.

Attempt:

We want to show for all $C > 0$ there is some $N$ such that $\frac{1}{a_{2n}} > C$ for all $n \geq N$.

So let $C >0$ be arbitrary. If we can solve for $n$ in the following, I can choose $N$ correctly. So I need to solve for $n$ in 
$\frac{2n}{(-1)^{2n}} > C$

But the $(-1)^{2n}$ is confusing me because when I take logs and separate I end up with $\ln(2n) - 2n\ln(-1) > \ln(C)$, but since this is real analysis we can't have $\ln(-1)$...

Comment: Note that $(-1)^{2n} = ((-1)^2)^n = 1^n = 1$.

Comment: If you want to disprove your statement, you have to find a sequence which converges to infinity, and who's reciprocal does not converge to zero.

I think you will have a hard time finding one because it's false

Comment: However the converse statement, $\frac{1}{a_n} \to 0 \implies a_n \to \infty$ is false, and $a_n = n(-1)^n$ or your example will do the trick

Comment: Ahh I typed it the wrong way in my original post. I meant that I want to show that the opposite of $(a_{n}) \to 0 \Leftrightarrow (\frac{1}{a_{n}}) \to \infty$ is false

Comment: Yeah sure. So in your example $a_{2n} = n \to \infty$, and $a_{2n-1} = -n \to -\infty$. Since there are two subsequences with distinct limits, the sequence $a_n$ diverges, i.e. does not converge to $+\infty$.

Comment: Yes, I was just struggling to formally prove it, but @PrudiiArca sorts it out for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are complicating things too much.

Simply noting what happens for $n$ odd, and $n$  even suffices.

Note that :
$$
a_n = \begin{cases}
\frac 1n & n \text{ even} \\
\frac {-1}n & n \text{ odd} 
\end{cases}
$$

and therefore :
$$
\frac1{a_n} = \begin{cases}
n & n \text{ even} \\
-n & n \text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$$

Now it is almost obvious that $\frac 1{a_{2k}} \to \infty$ and $\frac 1{a_{2k+1}} \to - \infty$ : the formal proof is an exercise in understanding the definition, really.

Comment: Yes I just wanted practice using the definition, I know that it is obvious though.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.